# made up of "many tiny invisible bits" or "many tiny invisible bit"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number

In the context of something is made up of many tiny part(s), which is the correct sentence/grammar.

made up of many tiny invisible bits

or

made up of many tiny invisible bit ?

also would I need comma after tiny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "bits."

Let's break this down. You have a phrase *made up of [noun phrase]*. That noun phrase has a noun (*bit/bits*) that is modified by *many*, *tiny*, and *invisible*. Because of the word *many*, we know there are more than one *bit*.  Therefore, we need a plural noun. (By the way, the word *bit* is not a mass/uncountable noun -- contrast with a word like *stuff*.)

You don't need a comma after "tiny." The phrase *made up of many tiny invisible bits* is fine as is. However, if you chose to include a comma (*made up of many tiny, invisible bits*) that would be perfectly fine; the difference is that in the latter example there is more emphasis on each individual quality. That is, including the comma focuses the user on both the tininess and the invisibility as being significant qualities on their own.